# Reporting progress in a console app using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I have the following code (below) that mostly works but I'm not getting the expected output.  I'm trying to get a line printed to the console for each item that is processed.  I want to show the percentage complete as the tasks complete.

This is the output I get (the first few rows repeat).  I don't expect them to repeat so I know I've got something wrong.  No matter how many times I run this, the first few lines are the same.  Is it possible to get the output to show 1 --> 10 %, 2 --> 20 %, etc?

```
2 --> 20 %  -- Bytes Read = 23971
2 --> 20 %  -- Bytes Read = 23971
2 --> 20 %  -- Bytes Read = 23971
3 --> 30 %  -- Bytes Read = 35909
4 --> 40 %  -- Bytes Read = 47872
5 --> 50 %  -- Bytes Read = 59824
6 --> 60 %  -- Bytes Read = 71775
7 --> 70 %  -- Bytes Read = 83746
8 --> 80 %  -- Bytes Read = 95701
9 --> 90 %  -- Bytes Read = 107686
Elapsed Time: : 702
Press Any Key
```

Here is the code I'm running

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RestSharpAsyncTest
{
    public class SomeItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public long BytesRead { get; set; }

        public SomeItem(int i)
        {
            this.Id = i;
            this.BytesRead = 0;
        }

        public long ProcessItem()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://www.google.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("", Method.GET);

            var restResponse = client.Execute(request);

            return restResponse.RawBytes.Length;
        }
    }

    public class ProgressReport
    {
        public int Counter { get; set; } = 0;
        public long TotalBytesRead { get; set; }
        public int PercentComplete { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static async Task DoSomethingAsync(List<SomeItem> someItems, IProgress<ProgressReport> progress)
        {
            /// Set up the local progress reporter
            ProgressReport progressReport = new ProgressReport();

            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(someItems, someItem =>
                {
                    long bytesRead = someItem.ProcessItem();
                    progressReport.Counter++;
                    progressReport.PercentComplete = (progressReport.Counter * 100) / someItems.Count;
                    progressReport.TotalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                    progress.Report(progressReport);                    
                });
            });

            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: : {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Progress<ProgressReport> pr = new Progress<ProgressReport>();
            pr.ProgressChanged += Pr_ProgressChanged;

            // Create some items
            List<SomeItem> someItems = new List<SomeItem>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
                someItems.Add(new SomeItem(i));

            await DoSomethingAsync(someItems, pr);

            Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Pr_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressReport e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e.Counter } --> { e.PercentComplete } %  -- Bytes Read = { e.TotalBytesRead }");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
I added the following but still end up with the same results.

```
public class Program
{
    private static object locker = new object();
```

then

```
lock (locker)
{
    progressReport.Counter++;
    progressReport.PercentComplete = (progressReport.Counter * 100) / someItems.Count;
    progressReport.TotalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    progress.Report(progressReport);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Wai Ha Lee.  I added the lock code as you suggested but I'm not seeing anything different.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of issues with your code. It is quite odd.

You shouldn't be using Task.Run, you should just use Parallel.ForEach() and then await on the ProcessItem which should be re-written to be an async method using the rest clients async methods.

Also, you have a big misconception about how the IProgress interface works. It's not synchronous. It's asynchronous. When you call Report() it actually puts a queue item into the thread pool to call the event handler. Since you are using a shared object, it's going to be updated by the time things get printed.

IProgress must NOT use shared objects to report in a multi-threaded environment!

Comment: Thanks SledgeHammer.  I'm new to the whole async process and have been gathering info from here and some videos I've watched.  The video used the Task.Run so that the WPF app he was working on was responsive.  I moved this code to a Windows app and the progress works much better.  At the end of the app, tt seems that Report() loses the last updates.  Thank you again.

Comment: @DrZ Task.Run() is for running background synchronous tasks. Your rest client should have async methods. If it doesn't, find a better rest client :). You should be using the async methods and awaiting on those.

Comment: @DrZ But for the sake of your "actual problem" of the progress not working correctly, it's because IProgress is async behind the scenes and the timing of when the event handler will get called is indeterminate :)